# angular 2 vs react for Asp.net MVC 5.2

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Do you prefer Angular 2 or React for ASP.NET MVC 5.2?  I have mainly found angular 2 documentation for Asp.net MVC, but I also found reactJs.net.  I am hesitant to use reactjs.net in favor of just regular React.js.  I havent found many blog posts about using MVC razr views with React.js.  Thoughts?

Comment: This isn't the right place for this discussion because it is entirely opinion based. You're better off finding some forums that are better suited for discussion, as opposed to a Q&A site. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from Asp.Net MVC background. Angular 2 would be better for you. I can tell you based on my 10 yrs of experience on Asp.Net & 5 yrs on Angular.

> Nowadays you hear a lot of new technologies around the web stuff and
>   with this post I want to show you a get-starting-guide how to start
>   with the following technologies in general. I want to show how to set
>   up an environment where you can start programming ASP.NET and Angular.
>   As I started I spent a lot of time setting up all my tools and stuff.
>   If you want to save this time: Go ahead reading.

Ref:
http://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/01/25/angular-and-asp-net-core-starter/